# Retrieve user (non-ephemeral) port range in C for Linux

Tags: c, linux, tcp, ip

I am writing a simple server application that allows the user to specify which port they wish to run the server on.

I see that IPPORT_USERRESERVED in in.h defines the lowest unprivileged port number available, but how do I **programatically** retrieve the port number that the ephemeral port range begins?

Comment: The range(s) are defined by a RFC.

Comment: According to this article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), the IANA suggests a range, but that OS's implement their own range that do not coincide with this suggestion.